# Height of sparkline

Tags: diagrams, fontsize, height

I'm trying to place a sparkline in a ctable using the `sparklines` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{sparklines}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
    caption     = Regression Variables,
    label       = tab:RegVar,
    pos     = h,
    mincapwidth = \textwidth,
    doinside = \small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
]{llll}{

}{
\FL     
Regression      & Data Sources      & Resolution       &Figur\ML
Inventory       & file1             & Weekly           &\begin{sparkline}{20}
\spark 
0.01 0.04039222 0.01099099 0.04039222 0.01198198 0.04039222 0.01297297 -0.04565813 0.01396396 -0.04565813 0.01495495 -0.04565813 0.01594595 -0.04565813 0.01693694 -0.09104063 0.01792793 -0.09104063 0.01891892 -0.09104063 0.01990991 -0.09104063 0.0209009 -0.09104063 0.02189189 -0.1902401 0.02288288 -0.1902401 0.02387387 -0.1902401 0.02486486 -0.1902401 0.02585586 -0.1902401 0.02684685 -0.1383101 0.02783784 -0.1383101 0.02882883 -0.1383101 0.02981982 -0.1383101 0.03081081 -0.1383101 0.0318018 -0.148107 0.03279279 -0.148107 0.03378378 -0.148107 0.03477477 -0.148107 0.03576577 -0.148107 0.03675676 -0.3207715 0.03774775 -0.3207715 0.03873874 -0.3207715 0.03972973 -0.3207715 0.04072072 -0.3207715 0.04171171 -0.2189944 0.0427027 -0.2189944 0.04369369 -0.2189944 0.04468468 -0.2189944 0.04567568 -0.2189944 0.04666667 -0.1636589 0.04765766 -0.1636589 0.04864865 -0.1636589 0.04963964 -0.1636589 0.05063063 -0.2613438 0.05162162 -0.2613438 0.05261261 -0.2613438 0.0536036 -0.2613438 0.0545946 -0.2945866 0.05558559 -0.2945866 0.05657658 -0.2945866 0.05756757 -0.2945866 0.05855856 -0.2945866 0.05954955 -0.3902137 0.06054054 -0.3902137 0.06153153 -0.3902137 0.06252252 -0.3902137 0.06351351 -0.3902137 0.0645045 -0.4048627 0.0654955 -0.4048627 0.06648649 -0.4048627 0.06747748 -0.4048627 0.06846847 -0.4048627 0.06945946 -0.6489096 0.07045045 -0.6489096 0.07144144 -0.6489096 0.07243243 -0.6489096 0.07342342 -0.6489096 0.07441441 -0.7956724 0.0754054 -0.7956724 0.0763964 -0.7956724 0.07738739 -0.7956724 0.07837838 -0.7956724 0.07936937 -0.5339617 0.08036036 -0.5339617 0.08135135 -0.5339617 0.08234234 -0.5339617 0.08333333 -0.5339617 0.08432432 -0.4161302 0.08531532 -0.4161302 0.0863063 -0.4161302 0.0872973 -0.4161302 0.08828829 -0.4161302 0.08927928 -0.4361027 0.09027027 -0.4361027 0.09126126 -0.4361027 0.09225225 -0.4361027 0.09324324 -0.4361027 0.09423423 -0.4252723 0.09522523 -0.4252723 0.09621622 -0.4252723 0.0972072 -0.4252723 0.0981982 -0.4252723 0.09918919 -0.5798262 0.1001802 -0.5798262 0.1011712 -0.5798262 0.1021622 -0.5798262 0.1031532 -0.5798262 0.1041441 -0.5181622 0.1051351 -0.5181622 0.1061261 -0.5181622 0.1071171 -0.5181622 0.1081081 -0.5181622 0.1090991 -0.617681 0.1100901 -0.617681 0.1110811 -0.617681 0.1120721 -0.617681 0.1130631 -0.5441084 0.1140541 -0.5441084 0.1150450 -0.5441084 0.1160360 -0.5441084 0.1170270 -0.4580295 0.1180180 -0.4580295 0.119009 -0.4580295 0.12 -0.4580295 0.120991 -0.4580295 0.1219820 -0.5204364 0.1229730 -0.5204364 0.1239640 -0.5204364 0.1249550 -0.5204364 0.1259459 -0.5204364 0.1269369 -0.4960217 0.1279279 -0.4960217 0.1289189 -0.4960217 0.1299099 -0.6629545 0.1309009 -0.6629545 0.1318919 -0.6629545 0.1328829 -0.6629545 0.1338739 -0.5699415 0.1348649 -0.5699415 0.1358559 -0.5699415 0.1368468 -0.5699415 0.1378378 -0.5699415 0.1388288 -0.7277313 0.1398198 -0.7277313 0.1408108 -0.7277313 0.1418018 -0.7277313 0.1427928 -0.7277313 0.1437838 -0.7458167 0.1447748 -0.7458167 0.1457658 -0.7458167 0.1467568 -0.7458167 0.1477477 -0.7535605 0.1487387 -0.7535605 0.1497297 -0.7535605 0.1507207 -0.7535605 0.1517117 -0.7535605 0.1527027 -0.77706 0.1536937 -0.77706 0.1546847 -0.77706 0.1556757 -0.77706 0.1566667 -0.77706 0.1576577 -0.9094492 0.1586486 -0.9094492 0.1596396 -0.9094492 0.1606306 -0.9094492 0.1616216 -0.9094492 0.1626126 -0.771535 0.1636036 -0.771535 0.1645946 -0.771535 0.1655856 -0.771535 0.1665766 -0.8243754 0.1675676 -0.8243754 0.1685586 -0.8243754 0.1695495 -0.8243754 0.1705405 -0.8243754 0.1715315 -0.7903039 0.1725225 -0.7903039 0.1735135 -0.7903039 0.1745045 -0.7903039 0.1754955 -0.7903039 0.1764865 -0.9260611 0.1774775 -0.9260611 0.1784685 -0.9260611 0.1794595 -0.9260611 0.1804505 -0.9260611 0.1814414 -0.9599395 0.1824324 -0.9599395 0.1834234 -0.9599395 0.1844144 -0.9599395 0.1854054 -0.9599395 0.1863964 -0.9369478 0.1873874 -0.9369478 0.1883784 -0.9369478 0.1893694 -0.9369478 0.1903604 -0.9369478 0.1913514 -0.838789 0.1923423 -0.838789 0.1933333 -0.838789 0.1943243 -0.838789 0.1953153 -0.838789 0.1963063 -0.9485943 0.1972973 -0.9485943 0.1982883 -0.9485943 0.1992793 -0.9485943 0.2002703 -0.9485943 0.2012613 -1 0.2022523 -1 0.2032432 -1 0.2042342 -1 0.2052252 -1 0.2062162 -0.8212667 0.2072072 -0.8212667 0.2081982 -0.8212667 0.2091892 -0.7979622 0.2101802 -0.7979622 0.2111712 -0.7979622 0.2121622 -0.7979622 0.2131532 -0.7979622 0.2141441 -0.8150064 0.2151351 -0.8150064 0.2161261 -0.8150064 0.2171171 -0.8150064 0.2181081 -0.8588814 0.2190991 -0.8588814 0.2200901 -0.8588814 0.2210811 -0.8588814 0.2220721 -0.8588814 0.2230631 -0.9261427 0.2240541 -0.9261427 0.2250450 -0.9261427 0.2260360 -0.9261427 0.2270270 -0.9261427 0.228018 -0.8493148 0.229009 -0.8493148 0.23 -0.8493148 0.230991 -0.8493148 0.231982 -0.7778045 0.2329730 -0.7778045 0.2339640 -0.7778045 0.2349550 -0.7778045 0.2359459 -0.7778045 0.2369369 -0.8427834 0.2379279 -0.8427834 0.2389189 -0.8427834 0.2399099 -0.8427834 0.2409009 -0.8427834 0.2418919 -0.725465 0.2428829 -0.725465 0.2438739 -0.725465 0.2448649 -0.725465 0.2458559 -0.725465 0.2468468 -0.78933 0.2478378 -0.78933 0.2488288 -0.78933 0.2498198 -0.78933 0.2508108 -0.78933 0.2518018 -0.8174899 0.2527928 -0.8174899 0.2537838 -0.8174899 0.2547748 -0.8174899 0.2557658 -0.8174899 0.2567568 -0.7768848 0.2577477 -0.7768848 0.2587387 -0.7768848 0.2597297 -0.7768848 0.2607207 -0.867693 0.2617117 -0.867693 0.2627027 -0.867693 0.2636937 -0.867693 0.2646847 -0.867693 0.2656757 -0.9384085 0.2666667 -0.9384085 0.2676577 -0.9384085 0.2686486 -0.9384085 0.2696396 -0.9384085 0.2706306 -0.851552 0.2716216 -0.851552 0.2726126 -0.851552 0.2736036 -0.851552 0.2745946 -0.851552 0.2755856 -0.7432253 0.2765766 -0.7432253 0.2775676 -0.7432253 0.2785586 -0.7432253 0.2795495 -0.7432253 0.2805405 -0.7061322 0.2815315 -0.7061322 0.2825225 -0.7061322 0.2835135 -0.7061322 0.2845045 -0.7061322 0.2854955 -0.7118327 0.2864865 -0.7118327 0.2874775 -0.7118327 0.2884685 -0.7118327 0.2894595 -0.7118327 0.2904505 -0.6893353 0.2914414 -0.6893353 0.2924324 -0.6893353 0.2934234 -0.6893353 0.2944144 -0.633198 0.2954054 -0.633198 0.2963964 -0.633198 0.2973874 -0.633198 0.2983784 -0.6518865 0.2993694 -0.6518865 0.3003604 -0.6518865 0.3013514 -0.6518865 0.3023423 -0.6518865 0.3033333 -0.5131221 0.3043243 -0.5131221 0.3053153 -0.5131221 0.3063063 -0.5131221 0.3072973 -0.5131221 0.3082883 -0.4394044 0.3092793 -0.4394044 0.3102703 -0.4394044 0.3112613 -0.4394044 0.3122523 -0.4394044 0.3132432 -0.4038468 0.3142342 -0.4038468 0.3152252 -0.4038468 0.3162162 -0.4038468 0.3172072 -0.4038468 0.3181982 -0.2737022 0.3191892 -0.2737022 0.3201802 -0.2737022 0.3211712 -0.2737022 0.3221622 -0.2737022 0.3231532 -0.1862005 0.3241441 -0.1862005 0.3251351 -0.1862005 0.3261261 -0.1862005 0.3271171 -0.1862005 0.3281081 -0.3088056 0.3290991 -0.3088056 0.3300901 -0.3088056 0.3310811 -0.3088056 0.3320721 -0.3088056 0.3330631 -0.2524458 0.3340541 -0.2524458 0.3350450 -0.2524458 0.3360360 -0.2524458 0.337027 -0.2524458 0.338018 -0.3066343 0.339009 -0.3066343 0.34 -0.3066343 0.340991 -0.3066343 0.341982 -0.3066343 0.342973 -0.2979940 0.3439640 -0.2979940 0.3449550 -0.2979940 0.3459459 -0.2979940 0.3469369 -0.2979940 0.3479279 -0.2701691 0.3489189 -0.2701691 0.3499099 -0.2701691 0.3509009 -0.2701691 0.3518919 -0.2701691 0.3528829 -0.3577305 0.3538739 -0.3577305 0.3548649 -0.3577305 0.3558559 -0.3577305 0.3568468 -0.4647794 0.3578378 -0.4647794 0.3588288 -0.4647794 0.3598198 -0.4647794 0.3608108 -0.5837987 0.3618018 -0.5837987 0.3627928 -0.5837987 0.3637838 -0.5837987 0.3647748 -0.5837987 0.3657658 -0.7012833 0.3667568 -0.7012833 0.3677477 -0.7012833 0.3687387 -0.7012833 0.3697297 -0.7012833 0.3707207 -0.673836 0.3717117 -0.673836 0.3727027 -0.673836 0.3736937 -0.673836 0.3746847 -0.6948385 0.3756757 -0.6948385 0.3766667 -0.6948385 0.3776577 -0.6815587 0.3786486 -0.6815587 0.3796396 -0.6815587 0.3806306 -0.6815587 0.3816216 -0.7859855 0.3826126 -0.7859855 0.3836036 -0.7859855 0.3845946 -0.7859855 0.3855856 -0.7859855 0.3865766 -0.7714502 0.3875676 -0.7714502 0.3885586 -0.7714502 0.3895495 -0.7714502 0.3905405 -0.7772213 0.3915315 -0.7772213 0.3925225 -0.7772213 0.3935135 -0.7772213 0.3945045 -0.7772213 0.3954955 -0.6388785 0.3964865 -0.6388785 0.3974775 -0.6388785 0.3984685 -0.6388785 0.3994595 -0.6388785 0.4004505 -0.7118723 0.4014414 -0.7118723 0.4024324 -0.7118723 0.4034234 -0.7118723 0.4044144 -0.7118723 0.4054054 -0.53348 0.4063964 -0.53348 0.4073874 -0.53348 0.4083784 -0.53348 0.4093694 -0.5454824 0.4103604 -0.5454824 0.4113514 -0.5454824 0.4123423 -0.5454824 0.4133333 -0.5454824 0.4143243 -0.5191489 0.4153153 -0.5191489 0.4163063 -0.5191489 0.4172973 -0.5191489 0.4182883 -0.5191489 0.4192793 -0.4654926 0.4202703 -0.4654926 0.4212613 -0.4654926 0.4222523 -0.4654926 0.4232432 -0.4654926 0.4242342 -0.4865644 0.4252252 -0.4865644 0.4262162 -0.4865644 0.4272072 -0.4865644 0.4281982 -0.4865644 0.4291892 -0.370591 0.4301802 -0.370591 0.4311712 -0.370591 0.4321622 -0.370591 0.4331532 -0.370591 0.4341441 -0.3269654 0.4351351 -0.3269654 0.4361261 -0.3269654 0.4371171 -0.3269654 0.4381081 -0.3269654 0.4390991 -0.3795027 0.4400901 -0.3795027 0.4410811 -0.3795027 0.4420721 -0.3795027 0.4430631 -0.3795027 0.4440541 -0.344519 0.4450450 -0.344519 0.446036 -0.344519 0.447027 -0.3859232 0.448018 -0.3859232 0.449009 -0.3859232 0.45 -0.3859232 0.450991 -0.3859232 0.451982 -0.3412220 0.452973 -0.3412220 0.453964 -0.3412220 0.454955 -0.3412220 0.4559459 -0.3412220 0.4569369 -0.3247736 0.4579279 -0.3247736 0.4589189 -0.3247736 0.4599099 -0.3247736 0.4609009 -0.2735777 0.4618919 -0.2735777 0.4628829 -0.2735777 0.4638739 -0.2735777 0.4648649 -0.2735777 0.4658559 -0.3394190 0.4668468 -0.3394190 0.4678378 -0.3394190 0.4688288 -0.3394190 0.4698198 -0.3394190 0.4708108 -0.3008510 0.4718018 -0.3008510 0.4727928 -0.3008510 0.4737838 -0.3008510 0.4747748 -0.3008510 0.4757658 -0.263327 0.4767568 -0.263327 0.4777477 -0.263327 0.4787387 -0.263327 0.4797297 -0.1970234 0.4807207 -0.1970234 0.4817117 -0.1970234 0.4827027 -0.1970234 0.4836937 -0.1970234 0.4846847 -0.1788102 0.4856757 -0.1788102 0.4866667 -0.1788102 0.4876577 -0.1788102 0.4886486 -0.08528692 0.4896396 -0.08528692 0.4906306 -0.08528692 0.4916216 -0.08528692 0.4926126 -0.08528692 0.4936036 -0.05886088 0.4945946 -0.05886088 0.4955856 -0.05886088 0.4965766 -0.05886088 0.4975676 -0.05886088 0.4985586 -0.02902577 0.4995495 -0.02902577 0.5005405 -0.02902577 0.5015315 -0.02902577 0.5025225 -0.09507856 0.5035135 -0.09507856 0.5045045 -0.09507856
0.5054955 -0.09507856 0.5064865 -0.09507856 0.5074775 -0.1553570 0.5084685 -0.1553570 0.5094595 -0.1553570 0.5104505 -0.1553570 0.5114414 -0.05452455 0.5124324 -0.05452455 0.5134234 -0.05452455 0.5144144 -0.05452455 0.5154054 -0.05452455 0.5163964 -0.06020499 0.5173874 -0.06020499 0.5183784 -0.06020499 0.5193694 -0.06020499 0.5203604 -0.06020499 0.5213514 -0.1185952 0.5223423 -0.1185952 0.5233333 -0.1185952 0.5243243 -0.1185952 0.5253153 -0.1185952 0.5263063 -0.1082957 0.5272973 -0.1082957 0.5282883 -0.1082957 0.5292793 -0.1082957 0.5302703 -0.1082957 0.5312613 -0.1474496 0.5322523 -0.1474496 0.5332432 -0.1474496 0.5342342 -0.1474496 0.5352252 -0.1474496 0.5362162 -0.235981 0.5372072 -0.235981 0.5381982 -0.235981 0.5391892 -0.235981 0.5401802 -0.2068708 0.5411712 -0.2068708 0.5421622 -0.2068708 0.5431532 -0.2068708 0.5441441 -0.3258565 0.5451351 -0.3258565 0.5461261 -0.3258565 0.5471171 -0.3258565 0.5481081 -0.3258565 0.5490991 -0.550012 0.5500901 -0.550012 0.5510811 -0.550012 0.5520721 -0.550012 0.5530631 -0.550012 0.554054 -0.4168597 0.555045 -0.4168597 0.556036 -0.4168597 0.557027 -0.4168597 0.558018 -0.4168597 0.559009 -0.3967566 0.56 -0.3967566 0.560991 -0.3967566 0.561982 -0.3967566 0.562973 -0.3967566 0.563964 -0.2825576 0.564955 -0.2825576 0.565946 -0.2825576 0.5669369 -0.2825576 0.5679279 -0.2825576 0.5689189 -0.3153637 0.5699099 -0.3153637 0.5709009 -0.3153637 0.5718919 -0.3153637 0.5728829 -0.3153637 0.5738739 -0.2498191 0.5748649 -0.2498191 0.5758559 -0.2498191 0.5768468 -0.2498191 0.5778378 -0.2498191 0.5788288 -0.1480062 0.5798198 -0.1480062 0.5808108 -0.1480062 0.5818018 -0.1480062 0.5827928 -0.1480062 0.5837838 -0.07978047 0.5847748 -0.07978047 0.5857658 -0.07978047 0.5867568 -0.07978047 0.5877477 -0.07978047 0.5887387 -0.1235271 0.5897297 -0.1235271 0.5907207 -0.1235271 0.5917117 -0.1235271 0.5927027 -0.1235271 0.5936937 -0.05531641 0.5946847 -0.05531641 0.5956757 -0.05531641 0.5966667 -0.05531641 0.5976577 -0.03709525 0.5986486 -0.03709525 0.5996396 -0.03709525 0.6006306 -0.03709525 0.6016216 0.02806833 0.6026126 0.02806833 0.6036036 0.02806833 0.6045946 0.02806833 0.6055856 0.02806833 0.6065766 0.06710189 0.6075676 0.06710189 0.6085586 0.06710189 0.6095495 0.06710189 0.6105405 0.06710189 0.6115315 0.1010416 0.6125225 0.1010416 0.6135135 0.1010416 0.6145045 0.1010416 0.6154955 0.1010416 0.6164865 0.1594458 0.6174775 0.1594458 0.6184685 0.1594458 0.6194595 0.1594458 0.6204505 0.1594458 0.6214414 0.1594458 0.6224324 0.01626551 0.6234234 0.01626551 0.6244144 0.01626551 0.6254054 0.01626551 0.6263964 0.01626551 0.6273874 0.1444813 0.6283784 0.1444813 0.6293694 0.1444813 0.6303604 0.1444813 0.6313514 0.2112599 0.6323423 0.2112599 0.6333333 0.2112599 0.6343243 0.2112599 0.6353153 0.2112599 0.6363063 0.2584803 0.6372973 0.2584803 0.6382883 0.2584803 0.6392793 0.2584803 0.6402703 0.2584803 0.6412613 0.1548445 0.6422523 0.1548445 0.6432432 0.1548445 0.6442342 0.1548445 0.6452252 0.1548445 0.6462162 0.2086690 0.6472072 0.2086690 0.6481982 0.2086690 0.6491892 0.2086690 0.6501802 0.2086690 0.6511712 0.2553463 0.6521622 0.2553463 0.6531532 0.2553463 0.6541441 0.2553463 0.6551351 0.3089286 0.6561261 0.3089286 0.6571171 0.3089286 0.6581081 0.3089286 0.6590991 0.3089286 0.6600901 0.3327296 0.6610811 0.3327296 0.6620721 0.3327296 0.663063 0.3327296 0.664054 0.3327296 0.665045 0.3491779 0.666036 0.3491779 0.667027 0.3491779 0.668018 0.3491779 0.669009 0.3491779 0.67 0.3852874 0.670991 0.3852874 0.671982 0.3852874 0.672973 0.3852874 0.673964 0.3852874 0.674955 0.4184301 0.675946 0.4184301 0.676937 0.4184301 0.6779279 0.3723023 0.6789189 0.3723023 0.6799099 0.3723023 0.6809009 0.3723023 0.6818919 0.3723023 0.6828829 0.4420375 0.6838739 0.4420375 0.6848649 0.4420375 0.6858559 0.4420375 0.6868468 0.4420375 0.6878378 0.3656313 0.6888288 0.3656313 0.6898198 0.3656313 0.6908108 0.3656313 0.6918018 0.3656313 0.6927928 0.4132663 0.6937838 0.4132663 0.6947748 0.4132663 0.6957658 0.4132663 0.6967568 0.4132663 0.6977477 0.4130172 0.6987387 0.4130172 0.6997297 0.4130172 0.7007207 0.4130172 0.7017117 0.471093 0.7027027 0.471093 0.7036937 0.471093 0.7046847 0.471093 0.7056757 0.471093 0.7066667 0.5693275 0.7076577 0.5693275 0.7086486 0.5693275 0.7096396 0.5693275 0.7106306 0.5693275 0.7116216 0.5004023 0.7126126 0.5004023 0.7136036 0.5004023 0.7145946 0.5004023 0.7155856 0.5004023 0.7165766 0.5583893 0.7175676 0.5583893 0.7185586 0.5583893 0.7195495 0.5583893 0.7205405 0.4584739 0.7215315 0.4584739 0.7225225 0.4584739 0.7235135 0.4584739 0.7245045 0.4584739 0.7254955 0.4880468 0.7264865 0.4880468 0.7274775 0.4880468 0.7284685 0.4880468 0.7294595 0.4880468 0.7304505 0.4607382 0.7314414 0.4607382 0.7324324 0.4607382 0.7334234 0.4607382 0.7344144 0.4607382 0.7354054 0.5033603 0.7363964 0.5033603 0.7373874 0.5033603 0.7383784 0.5033603 0.7393694 0.5033603 0.7403604 0.4639921 0.7413514 0.4639921 0.7423423 0.4639921 0.7433333 0.4639921 0.7443243 0.4639921 0.7453153 0.4102321 0.7463063 0.4102321 0.7472973 0.4102321 0.7482883 0.4102321 0.7492793 0.4102321 0.7502703 0.3973476 0.7512613 0.3973476 0.7522523 0.3973476 0.7532432 0.3973476 0.7542342 0.3973476 0.7552252 0.3859574 0.7562162 0.3859574 0.7572072 0.3859574 0.7581982 0.3859574 0.7591892 0.3859574 0.7601802 0.4392997 0.7611712 0.4392997 0.7621622 0.4392997 0.7631532 0.4392997 0.7641441 0.4392997 0.7651351 0.5236798 0.7661261 0.5236798 0.7671171 0.5236798 0.7681081 0.5236798 0.7690991 0.5236798 0.7700901 0.5764471 0.7710811 0.5764471 0.772072 0.5764471 0.773063 0.5764471 0.774054 0.5764471 0.775045 0.6498502 0.776036 0.6498502 0.777027 0.6498502 0.778018 0.6498502 0.779009 0.6498502 0.78 0.6052627 0.780991 0.6052627 0.781982 0.6052627 0.782973 0.6052627 0.783964 0.5014514 0.784955 0.5014514 0.785946 0.5014514 0.786937 0.5014514 0.787928 0.4142086 0.7889189 0.4142086 0.7899099 0.4142086 0.7909009 0.4142086 0.7918919 0.4142086 0.7928829 0.4632936 0.7938739 0.4632936 0.7948649 0.4632936 0.7958559 0.4632936 0.7968468 0.4632936 0.7978378 0.4463942 0.7988288 0.4463942 0.7998198 0.4463942 0.8008108 0.4463942 0.8018018 0.4463942 0.8027928 0.4590706 0.8037838 0.4590706 0.8047748 0.4590706 0.8057658 0.4590706 0.8067568 0.4590706 0.8077477 0.4678455 0.8087387 0.4678455 0.8097297 0.4678455 0.8107207 0.4678455 0.8117117 0.4678455 0.8127027 0.548241 0.8136937 0.548241 0.8146847 0.548241 0.8156757 0.548241 0.8166667 0.548241 0.8176577 0.588082 0.8186486 0.588082 0.8196396 0.588082 0.8206306 0.588082 0.8216216 0.588082 0.8226126 0.6015888 0.8236036 0.6015888 0.8245946 0.6015888 0.8255856 0.6015888 0.8265766 0.6015888 0.8275676 0.6387331 0.8285586 0.6387331 0.8295495 0.6387331 0.8305405 0.6387331 0.8315315 0.6387331 0.8325225 0.6155009 0.8335135 0.6155009 0.8345045 0.6155009 0.8354955 0.6155009 0.8364865 0.6155009 0.8374775 0.5645217 0.8384685 0.5645217 0.8394595 0.5645217 0.8404505 0.5645217 0.8414414 0.5322565 0.8424324 0.5322565 0.8434234 0.5322565 0.8444144 0.5322565 0.8454054 0.5640038 0.8463964 0.5640038 0.8473874 0.5640038 0.8483784 0.5640038 0.8493694 0.5640038 0.8503604 0.626635 0.8513514 0.626635 0.8523423 0.626635 0.8533333 0.626635 0.8543243 0.626635 0.8553153 0.6704094 0.8563063 0.6704094 0.8572973 0.6704094 0.8582883 0.6704094 0.8592793 0.6704094 0.8602703 0.6466946 0.8612613 0.6466946 0.8622523 0.6466946 0.8632432 0.7058764 0.8642342 0.7058764 0.8652252 0.7058764 0.8662162 0.7058764 0.8672072 0.677703 0.8681982 0.677703 0.8691892 0.677703 0.8701802 0.677703 0.8711712 0.677703 0.8721622 0.7697361 0.8731532 0.7697361 0.8741441 0.7697361 0.8751351 0.7697361 0.8761261 0.6871 0.8771171 0.6871 0.8781081 0.6871 0.8790991 0.6871 0.8800901 0.6871 0.881081 0.7433981 0.882072 0.7433981 0.883063 0.7433981 0.884054 0.7433981 0.885045 0.7433981 0.886036 0.6772184 0.887027 0.6772184 0.888018 0.6772184 0.889009 0.6772184 0.89 0.6772184 0.890991 0.771042 0.891982 0.771042 0.892973 0.771042 0.893964 0.771042 0.894955 0.771042 0.895946 0.82236 0.896937 0.82236 0.897928 0.82236 0.898919 0.82236 0.8999099 0.8468922 0.9009009 0.8468922 0.9018919 0.8468922 0.9028829 0.8468922 0.9038739 0.8468922 0.9048649 0.9411 0.9058559 0.9411 0.9068468 0.9411 0.9078378 0.9411 0.9088288 0.9411 0.9098198 0.9859473 0.9108108 0.9859473 0.9118018 0.9859473 0.9127928 0.9859473 0.9137838 0.9859473 0.9147748 0.8998364 0.9157658 0.8998364 0.9167568 0.8998364 0.9177477 0.8998364 0.9187387 0.8998364 0.9197297 0.8364399 0.9207207 0.8364399 0.9217117 0.8364399 0.9227027 0.8364399 0.9236937 0.8364399 0.9246847 0.7796059 0.9256757 0.7796059 0.9266667 0.7796059 0.9276577 0.7796059 0.9286486 0.7796059 0.9296396 0.8325947 0.9306306 0.8325947 0.9316216 0.8325947 0.9326126 0.8325947 0.9336036 0.8325947 0.9345946 0.8086544 0.9355856 0.8086544 0.9365766 0.8086544 0.9375676 0.7417212 0.9385586 0.7417212 0.9395495 0.7417212 0.9405405 0.7417212 0.9415315 0.7417212 0.9425225 0.6961463 0.9435135 0.6961463 0.9445045 0.6961463 0.9454955 0.6961463 0.9464865 0.7140584 0.9474775 0.7140584 0.9484685 0.7140584 0.9494595 0.7140584 0.9504505 0.7140584 0.9514414 0.7086224 0.9524324 0.7086224 0.9534234 0.7086224 0.9544144 0.7086224 0.9554054 0.7086224 0.9563964 0.6277234 0.9573874 0.6277234 0.9583784 0.6277234 0.9593694 0.6277234 0.9603604 0.6277234 0.9613514 0.6609766 0.9623423 0.6609766 0.9633333 0.6609766 0.9643243 0.6609766 0.9653153 0.6401879 0.9663063 0.6401879 0.9672973 0.6401879 0.9682883 0.6401879 0.9692793 0.6401879 0.9702703 0.6867343 0.9712613 0.6867343 0.9722523 0.6867343 0.9732432 0.6867343 0.9742342 0.6867343 0.9752252 0.704195 0.9762162 0.704195 0.9772072 0.704195 0.9781982 0.704195 0.9791892 0.704195 0.9801802 0.6585296 0.9811712 0.6585296 0.9821622 0.6585296 0.9831532 0.6585296 0.9841441 0.6585296 0.9851351 0.6520931 0.9861261 0.6520931 0.9871171 0.6520931 0.9881081 0.6520931 0.9890991 0.5826448 0.99009 0.5826448 0.991081 0.5826448 0.992072 0.5826448 0.993063 0.5826448 0.994054 0.5926264 0.995045 0.5926264 0.996036 0.5926264 0.997027 0.5926264 0.998018 0.5926264 0.999009 0.637794 1 0.637794 /
\end{sparkline}
\NN
SPSPz           & file2             & Weekly           &*sparkline2*\LL 
}

\end{document}
```

From the `doinside = \small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` the line spacing is set to 1.5. I would like the sparkline to have the same height, so i fits into the table... Have tried 
`\sparklineheight`, but can't get i to work...

Comment: Redefining the *macro* `\sparklineheight` to a different factor (default is 1.75) should do it. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Please add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that produces the table so people can simply add and test there solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is some vertical space in the row for the sparkline. In the following code I used a `\rule` with `0pt` width and height and `-3ex` depth and the used `\raisebox` (from `graphicx`) to adjust the vertical placement:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{sparklines}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
    caption     = Regression Variables,
    label       = tab:RegVar,
    pos     = h,
    mincapwidth = \textwidth,
    doinside = \small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
]{llll}{

}{
\FL     
Regression      & Data Sources      & Resolution       &Figur\ML
Inventory       & file1             & Weekly          &\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{0pt}\renewcommand\sparklineheight{2}
\raisebox{2pt}{
\begin{sparkline}{20}
\spark 
0.01 0.04039222 0.01099099 0.04039222 0.01198198 0.04039222 0.01297297 -0.04565813 0.01396396 -0.04565813 0.01495495 -0.04565813 0.01594595 -0.04565813 0.01693694 -0.09104063 0.01792793 -0.09104063 0.01891892 -0.09104063 0.01990991 -0.09104063 0.0209009 -0.09104063 0.02189189 -0.1902401 0.02288288 -0.1902401 0.02387387 -0.1902401 0.02486486 -0.1902401 0.02585586 -0.1902401 0.02684685 -0.1383101 0.02783784 -0.1383101 0.02882883 -0.1383101 0.02981982 -0.1383101 0.03081081 -0.1383101 0.0318018 -0.148107 0.03279279 -0.148107 0.03378378 -0.148107 0.03477477 -0.148107 0.03576577 -0.148107 0.03675676 -0.3207715 0.03774775 -0.3207715 0.03873874 -0.3207715 0.03972973 -0.3207715 0.04072072 -0.3207715 0.04171171 -0.2189944 0.0427027 -0.2189944 0.04369369 -0.2189944 0.04468468 -0.2189944 0.04567568 -0.2189944 0.04666667 -0.1636589 0.04765766 -0.1636589 0.04864865 -0.1636589 0.04963964 -0.1636589 0.05063063 -0.2613438 0.05162162 -0.2613438 0.05261261 -0.2613438 0.0536036 -0.2613438 0.0545946 -0.2945866 0.05558559 -0.2945866 0.05657658 -0.2945866 0.05756757 -0.2945866 0.05855856 -0.2945866 0.05954955 -0.3902137 0.06054054 -0.3902137 0.06153153 -0.3902137 0.06252252 -0.3902137 0.06351351 -0.3902137 0.0645045 -0.4048627 0.0654955 -0.4048627 0.06648649 -0.4048627 0.06747748 -0.4048627 0.06846847 -0.4048627 0.06945946 -0.6489096 0.07045045 -0.6489096 0.07144144 -0.6489096 0.07243243 -0.6489096 0.07342342 -0.6489096 0.07441441 -0.7956724 0.0754054 -0.7956724 0.0763964 -0.7956724 0.07738739 -0.7956724 0.07837838 -0.7956724 0.07936937 -0.5339617 0.08036036 -0.5339617 0.08135135 -0.5339617 0.08234234 -0.5339617 0.08333333 -0.5339617 0.08432432 -0.4161302 0.08531532 -0.4161302 0.0863063 -0.4161302 0.0872973 -0.4161302 0.08828829 -0.4161302 0.08927928 -0.4361027 0.09027027 -0.4361027 0.09126126 -0.4361027 0.09225225 -0.4361027 0.09324324 -0.4361027 0.09423423 -0.4252723 0.09522523 -0.4252723 0.09621622 -0.4252723 0.0972072 -0.4252723 0.0981982 -0.4252723 0.09918919 -0.5798262 0.1001802 -0.5798262 0.1011712 -0.5798262 0.1021622 -0.5798262 0.1031532 -0.5798262 0.1041441 -0.5181622 0.1051351 -0.5181622 0.1061261 -0.5181622 0.1071171 -0.5181622 0.1081081 -0.5181622 0.1090991 -0.617681 0.1100901 -0.617681 0.1110811 -0.617681 0.1120721 -0.617681 0.1130631 -0.5441084 0.1140541 -0.5441084 0.1150450 -0.5441084 0.1160360 -0.5441084 0.1170270 -0.4580295 0.1180180 -0.4580295 0.119009 -0.4580295 0.12 -0.4580295 0.120991 -0.4580295 0.1219820 -0.5204364 0.1229730 -0.5204364 0.1239640 -0.5204364 0.1249550 -0.5204364 0.1259459 -0.5204364 0.1269369 -0.4960217 0.1279279 -0.4960217 0.1289189 -0.4960217 0.1299099 -0.6629545 0.1309009 -0.6629545 0.1318919 -0.6629545 0.1328829 -0.6629545 0.1338739 -0.5699415 0.1348649 -0.5699415 0.1358559 -0.5699415 0.1368468 -0.5699415 0.1378378 -0.5699415 0.1388288 -0.7277313 0.1398198 -0.7277313 0.1408108 -0.7277313 0.1418018 -0.7277313 0.1427928 -0.7277313 0.1437838 -0.7458167 0.1447748 -0.7458167 0.1457658 -0.7458167 0.1467568 -0.7458167 0.1477477 -0.7535605 0.1487387 -0.7535605 0.1497297 -0.7535605 0.1507207 -0.7535605 0.1517117 -0.7535605 0.1527027 -0.77706 0.1536937 -0.77706 0.1546847 -0.77706 0.1556757 -0.77706 0.1566667 -0.77706 0.1576577 -0.9094492 0.1586486 -0.9094492 0.1596396 -0.9094492 0.1606306 -0.9094492 0.1616216 -0.9094492 0.1626126 -0.771535 0.1636036 -0.771535 0.1645946 -0.771535 0.1655856 -0.771535 0.1665766 -0.8243754 0.1675676 -0.8243754 0.1685586 -0.8243754 0.1695495 -0.8243754 0.1705405 -0.8243754 0.1715315 -0.7903039 0.1725225 -0.7903039 0.1735135 -0.7903039 0.1745045 -0.7903039 0.1754955 -0.7903039 0.1764865 -0.9260611 0.1774775 -0.9260611 0.1784685 -0.9260611 0.1794595 -0.9260611 0.1804505 -0.9260611 0.1814414 -0.9599395 0.1824324 -0.9599395 0.1834234 -0.9599395 0.1844144 -0.9599395 0.1854054 -0.9599395 0.1863964 -0.9369478 0.1873874 -0.9369478 0.1883784 -0.9369478 0.1893694 -0.9369478 0.1903604 -0.9369478 0.1913514 -0.838789 0.1923423 -0.838789 0.1933333 -0.838789 0.1943243 -0.838789 0.1953153 -0.838789 0.1963063 -0.9485943 0.1972973 -0.9485943 0.1982883 -0.9485943 0.1992793 -0.9485943 0.2002703 -0.9485943 0.2012613 -1 0.2022523 -1 0.2032432 -1 0.2042342 -1 0.2052252 -1 0.2062162 -0.8212667 0.2072072 -0.8212667 0.2081982 -0.8212667 0.2091892 -0.7979622 0.2101802 -0.7979622 0.2111712 -0.7979622 0.2121622 -0.7979622 0.2131532 -0.7979622 0.2141441 -0.8150064 0.2151351 -0.8150064 0.2161261 -0.8150064 0.2171171 -0.8150064 0.2181081 -0.8588814 0.2190991 -0.8588814 0.2200901 -0.8588814 0.2210811 -0.8588814 0.2220721 -0.8588814 0.2230631 -0.9261427 0.2240541 -0.9261427 0.2250450 -0.9261427 0.2260360 -0.9261427 0.2270270 -0.9261427 0.228018 -0.8493148 0.229009 -0.8493148 0.23 -0.8493148 0.230991 -0.8493148 0.231982 -0.7778045 0.2329730 -0.7778045 0.2339640 -0.7778045 0.2349550 -0.7778045 0.2359459 -0.7778045 0.2369369 -0.8427834 0.2379279 -0.8427834 0.2389189 -0.8427834 0.2399099 -0.8427834 0.2409009 -0.8427834 0.2418919 -0.725465 0.2428829 -0.725465 0.2438739 -0.725465 0.2448649 -0.725465 0.2458559 -0.725465 0.2468468 -0.78933 0.2478378 -0.78933 0.2488288 -0.78933 0.2498198 -0.78933 0.2508108 -0.78933 0.2518018 -0.8174899 0.2527928 -0.8174899 0.2537838 -0.8174899 0.2547748 -0.8174899 0.2557658 -0.8174899 0.2567568 -0.7768848 0.2577477 -0.7768848 0.2587387 -0.7768848 0.2597297 -0.7768848 0.2607207 -0.867693 0.2617117 -0.867693 0.2627027 -0.867693 0.2636937 -0.867693 0.2646847 -0.867693 0.2656757 -0.9384085 0.2666667 -0.9384085 0.2676577 -0.9384085 0.2686486 -0.9384085 0.2696396 -0.9384085 0.2706306 -0.851552 0.2716216 -0.851552 0.2726126 -0.851552 0.2736036 -0.851552 0.2745946 -0.851552 0.2755856 -0.7432253 0.2765766 -0.7432253 0.2775676 -0.7432253 0.2785586 -0.7432253 0.2795495 -0.7432253 0.2805405 -0.7061322 0.2815315 -0.7061322 0.2825225 -0.7061322 0.2835135 -0.7061322 0.2845045 -0.7061322 0.2854955 -0.7118327 0.2864865 -0.7118327 0.2874775 -0.7118327 0.2884685 -0.7118327 0.2894595 -0.7118327 0.2904505 -0.6893353 0.2914414 -0.6893353 0.2924324 -0.6893353 0.2934234 -0.6893353 0.2944144 -0.633198 0.2954054 -0.633198 0.2963964 -0.633198 0.2973874 -0.633198 0.2983784 -0.6518865 0.2993694 -0.6518865 0.3003604 -0.6518865 0.3013514 -0.6518865 0.3023423 -0.6518865 0.3033333 -0.5131221 0.3043243 -0.5131221 0.3053153 -0.5131221 0.3063063 -0.5131221 0.3072973 -0.5131221 0.3082883 -0.4394044 0.3092793 -0.4394044 0.3102703 -0.4394044 0.3112613 -0.4394044 0.3122523 -0.4394044 0.3132432 -0.4038468 0.3142342 -0.4038468 0.3152252 -0.4038468 0.3162162 -0.4038468 0.3172072 -0.4038468 0.3181982 -0.2737022 0.3191892 -0.2737022 0.3201802 -0.2737022 0.3211712 -0.2737022 0.3221622 -0.2737022 0.3231532 -0.1862005 0.3241441 -0.1862005 0.3251351 -0.1862005 0.3261261 -0.1862005 0.3271171 -0.1862005 0.3281081 -0.3088056 0.3290991 -0.3088056 0.3300901 -0.3088056 0.3310811 -0.3088056 0.3320721 -0.3088056 0.3330631 -0.2524458 0.3340541 -0.2524458 0.3350450 -0.2524458 0.3360360 -0.2524458 0.337027 -0.2524458 0.338018 -0.3066343 0.339009 -0.3066343 0.34 -0.3066343 0.340991 -0.3066343 0.341982 -0.3066343 0.342973 -0.2979940 0.3439640 -0.2979940 0.3449550 -0.2979940 0.3459459 -0.2979940 0.3469369 -0.2979940 0.3479279 -0.2701691 0.3489189 -0.2701691 0.3499099 -0.2701691 0.3509009 -0.2701691 0.3518919 -0.2701691 0.3528829 -0.3577305 0.3538739 -0.3577305 0.3548649 -0.3577305 0.3558559 -0.3577305 0.3568468 -0.4647794 0.3578378 -0.4647794 0.3588288 -0.4647794 0.3598198 -0.4647794 0.3608108 -0.5837987 0.3618018 -0.5837987 0.3627928 -0.5837987 0.3637838 -0.5837987 0.3647748 -0.5837987 0.3657658 -0.7012833 0.3667568 -0.7012833 0.3677477 -0.7012833 0.3687387 -0.7012833 0.3697297 -0.7012833 0.3707207 -0.673836 0.3717117 -0.673836 0.3727027 -0.673836 0.3736937 -0.673836 0.3746847 -0.6948385 0.3756757 -0.6948385 0.3766667 -0.6948385 0.3776577 -0.6815587 0.3786486 -0.6815587 0.3796396 -0.6815587 0.3806306 -0.6815587 0.3816216 -0.7859855 0.3826126 -0.7859855 0.3836036 -0.7859855 0.3845946 -0.7859855 0.3855856 -0.7859855 0.3865766 -0.7714502 0.3875676 -0.7714502 0.3885586 -0.7714502 0.3895495 -0.7714502 0.3905405 -0.7772213 0.3915315 -0.7772213 0.3925225 -0.7772213 0.3935135 -0.7772213 0.3945045 -0.7772213 0.3954955 -0.6388785 0.3964865 -0.6388785 0.3974775 -0.6388785 0.3984685 -0.6388785 0.3994595 -0.6388785 0.4004505 -0.7118723 0.4014414 -0.7118723 0.4024324 -0.7118723 0.4034234 -0.7118723 0.4044144 -0.7118723 0.4054054 -0.53348 0.4063964 -0.53348 0.4073874 -0.53348 0.4083784 -0.53348 0.4093694 -0.5454824 0.4103604 -0.5454824 0.4113514 -0.5454824 0.4123423 -0.5454824 0.4133333 -0.5454824 0.4143243 -0.5191489 0.4153153 -0.5191489 0.4163063 -0.5191489 0.4172973 -0.5191489 0.4182883 -0.5191489 0.4192793 -0.4654926 0.4202703 -0.4654926 0.4212613 -0.4654926 0.4222523 -0.4654926 0.4232432 -0.4654926 0.4242342 -0.4865644 0.4252252 -0.4865644 0.4262162 -0.4865644 0.4272072 -0.4865644 0.4281982 -0.4865644 0.4291892 -0.370591 0.4301802 -0.370591 0.4311712 -0.370591 0.4321622 -0.370591 0.4331532 -0.370591 0.4341441 -0.3269654 0.4351351 -0.3269654 0.4361261 -0.3269654 0.4371171 -0.3269654 0.4381081 -0.3269654 0.4390991 -0.3795027 0.4400901 -0.3795027 0.4410811 -0.3795027 0.4420721 -0.3795027 0.4430631 -0.3795027 0.4440541 -0.344519 0.4450450 -0.344519 0.446036 -0.344519 0.447027 -0.3859232 0.448018 -0.3859232 0.449009 -0.3859232 0.45 -0.3859232 0.450991 -0.3859232 0.451982 -0.3412220 0.452973 -0.3412220 0.453964 -0.3412220 0.454955 -0.3412220 0.4559459 -0.3412220 0.4569369 -0.3247736 0.4579279 -0.3247736 0.4589189 -0.3247736 0.4599099 -0.3247736 0.4609009 -0.2735777 0.4618919 -0.2735777 0.4628829 -0.2735777 0.4638739 -0.2735777 0.4648649 -0.2735777 0.4658559 -0.3394190 0.4668468 -0.3394190 0.4678378 -0.3394190 0.4688288 -0.3394190 0.4698198 -0.3394190 0.4708108 -0.3008510 0.4718018 -0.3008510 0.4727928 -0.3008510 0.4737838 -0.3008510 0.4747748 -0.3008510 0.4757658 -0.263327 0.4767568 -0.263327 0.4777477 -0.263327 0.4787387 -0.263327 0.4797297 -0.1970234 0.4807207 -0.1970234 0.4817117 -0.1970234 0.4827027 -0.1970234 0.4836937 -0.1970234 0.4846847 -0.1788102 0.4856757 -0.1788102 0.4866667 -0.1788102 0.4876577 -0.1788102 0.4886486 -0.08528692 0.4896396 -0.08528692 0.4906306 -0.08528692 0.4916216 -0.08528692 0.4926126 -0.08528692 0.4936036 -0.05886088 0.4945946 -0.05886088 0.4955856 -0.05886088 0.4965766 -0.05886088 0.4975676 -0.05886088 0.4985586 -0.02902577 0.4995495 -0.02902577 0.5005405 -0.02902577 0.5015315 -0.02902577 0.5025225 -0.09507856 0.5035135 -0.09507856 0.5045045 -0.09507856
0.5054955 -0.09507856 0.5064865 -0.09507856 0.5074775 -0.1553570 0.5084685 -0.1553570 0.5094595 -0.1553570 0.5104505 -0.1553570 0.5114414 -0.05452455 0.5124324 -0.05452455 0.5134234 -0.05452455 0.5144144 -0.05452455 0.5154054 -0.05452455 0.5163964 -0.06020499 0.5173874 -0.06020499 0.5183784 -0.06020499 0.5193694 -0.06020499 0.5203604 -0.06020499 0.5213514 -0.1185952 0.5223423 -0.1185952 0.5233333 -0.1185952 0.5243243 -0.1185952 0.5253153 -0.1185952 0.5263063 -0.1082957 0.5272973 -0.1082957 0.5282883 -0.1082957 0.5292793 -0.1082957 0.5302703 -0.1082957 0.5312613 -0.1474496 0.5322523 -0.1474496 0.5332432 -0.1474496 0.5342342 -0.1474496 0.5352252 -0.1474496 0.5362162 -0.235981 0.5372072 -0.235981 0.5381982 -0.235981 0.5391892 -0.235981 0.5401802 -0.2068708 0.5411712 -0.2068708 0.5421622 -0.2068708 0.5431532 -0.2068708 0.5441441 -0.3258565 0.5451351 -0.3258565 0.5461261 -0.3258565 0.5471171 -0.3258565 0.5481081 -0.3258565 0.5490991 -0.550012 0.5500901 -0.550012 0.5510811 -0.550012 0.5520721 -0.550012 0.5530631 -0.550012 0.554054 -0.4168597 0.555045 -0.4168597 0.556036 -0.4168597 0.557027 -0.4168597 0.558018 -0.4168597 0.559009 -0.3967566 0.56 -0.3967566 0.560991 -0.3967566 0.561982 -0.3967566 0.562973 -0.3967566 0.563964 -0.2825576 0.564955 -0.2825576 0.565946 -0.2825576 0.5669369 -0.2825576 0.5679279 -0.2825576 0.5689189 -0.3153637 0.5699099 -0.3153637 0.5709009 -0.3153637 0.5718919 -0.3153637 0.5728829 -0.3153637 0.5738739 -0.2498191 0.5748649 -0.2498191 0.5758559 -0.2498191 0.5768468 -0.2498191 0.5778378 -0.2498191 0.5788288 -0.1480062 0.5798198 -0.1480062 0.5808108 -0.1480062 0.5818018 -0.1480062 0.5827928 -0.1480062 0.5837838 -0.07978047 0.5847748 -0.07978047 0.5857658 -0.07978047 0.5867568 -0.07978047 0.5877477 -0.07978047 0.5887387 -0.1235271 0.5897297 -0.1235271 0.5907207 -0.1235271 0.5917117 -0.1235271 0.5927027 -0.1235271 0.5936937 -0.05531641 0.5946847 -0.05531641 0.5956757 -0.05531641 0.5966667 -0.05531641 0.5976577 -0.03709525 0.5986486 -0.03709525 0.5996396 -0.03709525 0.6006306 -0.03709525 0.6016216 0.02806833 0.6026126 0.02806833 0.6036036 0.02806833 0.6045946 0.02806833 0.6055856 0.02806833 0.6065766 0.06710189 0.6075676 0.06710189 0.6085586 0.06710189 0.6095495 0.06710189 0.6105405 0.06710189 0.6115315 0.1010416 0.6125225 0.1010416 0.6135135 0.1010416 0.6145045 0.1010416 0.6154955 0.1010416 0.6164865 0.1594458 0.6174775 0.1594458 0.6184685 0.1594458 0.6194595 0.1594458 0.6204505 0.1594458 0.6214414 0.1594458 0.6224324 0.01626551 0.6234234 0.01626551 0.6244144 0.01626551 0.6254054 0.01626551 0.6263964 0.01626551 0.6273874 0.1444813 0.6283784 0.1444813 0.6293694 0.1444813 0.6303604 0.1444813 0.6313514 0.2112599 0.6323423 0.2112599 0.6333333 0.2112599 0.6343243 0.2112599 0.6353153 0.2112599 0.6363063 0.2584803 0.6372973 0.2584803 0.6382883 0.2584803 0.6392793 0.2584803 0.6402703 0.2584803 0.6412613 0.1548445 0.6422523 0.1548445 0.6432432 0.1548445 0.6442342 0.1548445 0.6452252 0.1548445 0.6462162 0.2086690 0.6472072 0.2086690 0.6481982 0.2086690 0.6491892 0.2086690 0.6501802 0.2086690 0.6511712 0.2553463 0.6521622 0.2553463 0.6531532 0.2553463 0.6541441 0.2553463 0.6551351 0.3089286 0.6561261 0.3089286 0.6571171 0.3089286 0.6581081 0.3089286 0.6590991 0.3089286 0.6600901 0.3327296 0.6610811 0.3327296 0.6620721 0.3327296 0.663063 0.3327296 0.664054 0.3327296 0.665045 0.3491779 0.666036 0.3491779 0.667027 0.3491779 0.668018 0.3491779 0.669009 0.3491779 0.67 0.3852874 0.670991 0.3852874 0.671982 0.3852874 0.672973 0.3852874 0.673964 0.3852874 0.674955 0.4184301 0.675946 0.4184301 0.676937 0.4184301 0.6779279 0.3723023 0.6789189 0.3723023 0.6799099 0.3723023 0.6809009 0.3723023 0.6818919 0.3723023 0.6828829 0.4420375 0.6838739 0.4420375 0.6848649 0.4420375 0.6858559 0.4420375 0.6868468 0.4420375 0.6878378 0.3656313 0.6888288 0.3656313 0.6898198 0.3656313 0.6908108 0.3656313 0.6918018 0.3656313 0.6927928 0.4132663 0.6937838 0.4132663 0.6947748 0.4132663 0.6957658 0.4132663 0.6967568 0.4132663 0.6977477 0.4130172 0.6987387 0.4130172 0.6997297 0.4130172 0.7007207 0.4130172 0.7017117 0.471093 0.7027027 0.471093 0.7036937 0.471093 0.7046847 0.471093 0.7056757 0.471093 0.7066667 0.5693275 0.7076577 0.5693275 0.7086486 0.5693275 0.7096396 0.5693275 0.7106306 0.5693275 0.7116216 0.5004023 0.7126126 0.5004023 0.7136036 0.5004023 0.7145946 0.5004023 0.7155856 0.5004023 0.7165766 0.5583893 0.7175676 0.5583893 0.7185586 0.5583893 0.7195495 0.5583893 0.7205405 0.4584739 0.7215315 0.4584739 0.7225225 0.4584739 0.7235135 0.4584739 0.7245045 0.4584739 0.7254955 0.4880468 0.7264865 0.4880468 0.7274775 0.4880468 0.7284685 0.4880468 0.7294595 0.4880468 0.7304505 0.4607382 0.7314414 0.4607382 0.7324324 0.4607382 0.7334234 0.4607382 0.7344144 0.4607382 0.7354054 0.5033603 0.7363964 0.5033603 0.7373874 0.5033603 0.7383784 0.5033603 0.7393694 0.5033603 0.7403604 0.4639921 0.7413514 0.4639921 0.7423423 0.4639921 0.7433333 0.4639921 0.7443243 0.4639921 0.7453153 0.4102321 0.7463063 0.4102321 0.7472973 0.4102321 0.7482883 0.4102321 0.7492793 0.4102321 0.7502703 0.3973476 0.7512613 0.3973476 0.7522523 0.3973476 0.7532432 0.3973476 0.7542342 0.3973476 0.7552252 0.3859574 0.7562162 0.3859574 0.7572072 0.3859574 0.7581982 0.3859574 0.7591892 0.3859574 0.7601802 0.4392997 0.7611712 0.4392997 0.7621622 0.4392997 0.7631532 0.4392997 0.7641441 0.4392997 0.7651351 0.5236798 0.7661261 0.5236798 0.7671171 0.5236798 0.7681081 0.5236798 0.7690991 0.5236798 0.7700901 0.5764471 0.7710811 0.5764471 0.772072 0.5764471 0.773063 0.5764471 0.774054 0.5764471 0.775045 0.6498502 0.776036 0.6498502 0.777027 0.6498502 0.778018 0.6498502 0.779009 0.6498502 0.78 0.6052627 0.780991 0.6052627 0.781982 0.6052627 0.782973 0.6052627 0.783964 0.5014514 0.784955 0.5014514 0.785946 0.5014514 0.786937 0.5014514 0.787928 0.4142086 0.7889189 0.4142086 0.7899099 0.4142086 0.7909009 0.4142086 0.7918919 0.4142086 0.7928829 0.4632936 0.7938739 0.4632936 0.7948649 0.4632936 0.7958559 0.4632936 0.7968468 0.4632936 0.7978378 0.4463942 0.7988288 0.4463942 0.7998198 0.4463942 0.8008108 0.4463942 0.8018018 0.4463942 0.8027928 0.4590706 0.8037838 0.4590706 0.8047748 0.4590706 0.8057658 0.4590706 0.8067568 0.4590706 0.8077477 0.4678455 0.8087387 0.4678455 0.8097297 0.4678455 0.8107207 0.4678455 0.8117117 0.4678455 0.8127027 0.548241 0.8136937 0.548241 0.8146847 0.548241 0.8156757 0.548241 0.8166667 0.548241 0.8176577 0.588082 0.8186486 0.588082 0.8196396 0.588082 0.8206306 0.588082 0.8216216 0.588082 0.8226126 0.6015888 0.8236036 0.6015888 0.8245946 0.6015888 0.8255856 0.6015888 0.8265766 0.6015888 0.8275676 0.6387331 0.8285586 0.6387331 0.8295495 0.6387331 0.8305405 0.6387331 0.8315315 0.6387331 0.8325225 0.6155009 0.8335135 0.6155009 0.8345045 0.6155009 0.8354955 0.6155009 0.8364865 0.6155009 0.8374775 0.5645217 0.8384685 0.5645217 0.8394595 0.5645217 0.8404505 0.5645217 0.8414414 0.5322565 0.8424324 0.5322565 0.8434234 0.5322565 0.8444144 0.5322565 0.8454054 0.5640038 0.8463964 0.5640038 0.8473874 0.5640038 0.8483784 0.5640038 0.8493694 0.5640038 0.8503604 0.626635 0.8513514 0.626635 0.8523423 0.626635 0.8533333 0.626635 0.8543243 0.626635 0.8553153 0.6704094 0.8563063 0.6704094 0.8572973 0.6704094 0.8582883 0.6704094 0.8592793 0.6704094 0.8602703 0.6466946 0.8612613 0.6466946 0.8622523 0.6466946 0.8632432 0.7058764 0.8642342 0.7058764 0.8652252 0.7058764 0.8662162 0.7058764 0.8672072 0.677703 0.8681982 0.677703 0.8691892 0.677703 0.8701802 0.677703 0.8711712 0.677703 0.8721622 0.7697361 0.8731532 0.7697361 0.8741441 0.7697361 0.8751351 0.7697361 0.8761261 0.6871 0.8771171 0.6871 0.8781081 0.6871 0.8790991 0.6871 0.8800901 0.6871 0.881081 0.7433981 0.882072 0.7433981 0.883063 0.7433981 0.884054 0.7433981 0.885045 0.7433981 0.886036 0.6772184 0.887027 0.6772184 0.888018 0.6772184 0.889009 0.6772184 0.89 0.6772184 0.890991 0.771042 0.891982 0.771042 0.892973 0.771042 0.893964 0.771042 0.894955 0.771042 0.895946 0.82236 0.896937 0.82236 0.897928 0.82236 0.898919 0.82236 0.8999099 0.8468922 0.9009009 0.8468922 0.9018919 0.8468922 0.9028829 0.8468922 0.9038739 0.8468922 0.9048649 0.9411 0.9058559 0.9411 0.9068468 0.9411 0.9078378 0.9411 0.9088288 0.9411 0.9098198 0.9859473 0.9108108 0.9859473 0.9118018 0.9859473 0.9127928 0.9859473 0.9137838 0.9859473 0.9147748 0.8998364 0.9157658 0.8998364 0.9167568 0.8998364 0.9177477 0.8998364 0.9187387 0.8998364 0.9197297 0.8364399 0.9207207 0.8364399 0.9217117 0.8364399 0.9227027 0.8364399 0.9236937 0.8364399 0.9246847 0.7796059 0.9256757 0.7796059 0.9266667 0.7796059 0.9276577 0.7796059 0.9286486 0.7796059 0.9296396 0.8325947 0.9306306 0.8325947 0.9316216 0.8325947 0.9326126 0.8325947 0.9336036 0.8325947 0.9345946 0.8086544 0.9355856 0.8086544 0.9365766 0.8086544 0.9375676 0.7417212 0.9385586 0.7417212 0.9395495 0.7417212 0.9405405 0.7417212 0.9415315 0.7417212 0.9425225 0.6961463 0.9435135 0.6961463 0.9445045 0.6961463 0.9454955 0.6961463 0.9464865 0.7140584 0.9474775 0.7140584 0.9484685 0.7140584 0.9494595 0.7140584 0.9504505 0.7140584 0.9514414 0.7086224 0.9524324 0.7086224 0.9534234 0.7086224 0.9544144 0.7086224 0.9554054 0.7086224 0.9563964 0.6277234 0.9573874 0.6277234 0.9583784 0.6277234 0.9593694 0.6277234 0.9603604 0.6277234 0.9613514 0.6609766 0.9623423 0.6609766 0.9633333 0.6609766 0.9643243 0.6609766 0.9653153 0.6401879 0.9663063 0.6401879 0.9672973 0.6401879 0.9682883 0.6401879 0.9692793 0.6401879 0.9702703 0.6867343 0.9712613 0.6867343 0.9722523 0.6867343 0.9732432 0.6867343 0.9742342 0.6867343 0.9752252 0.704195 0.9762162 0.704195 0.9772072 0.704195 0.9781982 0.704195 0.9791892 0.704195 0.9801802 0.6585296 0.9811712 0.6585296 0.9821622 0.6585296 0.9831532 0.6585296 0.9841441 0.6585296 0.9851351 0.6520931 0.9861261 0.6520931 0.9871171 0.6520931 0.9881081 0.6520931 0.9890991 0.5826448 0.99009 0.5826448 0.991081 0.5826448 0.992072 0.5826448 0.993063 0.5826448 0.994054 0.5926264 0.995045 0.5926264 0.996036 0.5926264 0.997027 0.5926264 0.998018 0.5926264 0.999009 0.637794 1 0.637794 /
\end{sparkline}
}
\NN
SPSPz           & file2             & Weekly           &*sparkline2*\LL 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo Media: great, thks. Any way to put the 'spark data' in a separate text file?

Comment: @latexmp: an idea would be to compile the sparkline in a separate document using, for example, the `standalone` documentclass to get a .pdf file that you can then include in your table using the standard `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: @latexmp: You can put the `sparkline` environment incl. the data into a separate file and load it using `\input{<name>}` where you want it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the height of the sparkline using `\sparklineheight`. However, there are two issues. First the macro `\sparklineheight` awaits the height in `ex` units without the unit. Internally it is used as `\sparklineheight ex`, which is IMHO not a very good coding practice. You need to either calculate the height in `ex` and then remove the unit, e.g.:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\sparklineheight{\arraystretch\ht\strutbox / 1ex}
```

or define it like this:

```
\def\sparklineheight ex{15pt}
```

which removes the trailing `ex` (the 15pt is just an example).

The second issue is that this factor is simply setting the *height*, not the *total height* (height+depth) of the sparkline. Negative values go below the baseline and are part of the *depth*. Dependent on the used values you need a different height to fit both positive and negative values into the line.
The above values are to large because of this and you need to adjust them.

You could also raise the sparkline using
[`\raisebox{<length>}[<set height>][<set depth>]{<content>}`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#raisebox).

Comment: thnks, any way I can have the "spark data" in a separate txt file?